# Flutter webview http url not working in IOS

Tags: flutter, webview

I working on webview in flutter . I cant able to open  http url in IOS. It working on https. Can anyone suggest how to overcome this.

I put in info.plist

```
 <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
```

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple Transport Security needs to be disabled.

1. Open project in Xcode.
2. Open `Info.plist`
3. Add a new row to `Information Property List` (check id it's already there)

[image]

4. Select `App Transport Security Settings`
5. Make sure `Allow Arbitrary Loads` is set to `YES`

Comment: Thank you so much ilyas you saved time

Comment: Thanks, works. Info.plist: 
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: For me, this one solved my issue. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52249#issuecomment-598877903

Comment: thanks ilyas for your good explanation

Answer (score 18):

Add this to your Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Is the use of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` required, and if so, why? In my case, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` was enough.

Answer (score 2):

In case if your url has some special character. You need to encode the URL like this,

```js
WebView(
      initialUrl: Uri.encodeFull(EnterUrlHere),
      ...
 )
```

Comment: this worked for me, after wasting so much time

Answer (score 0):

> In iOS UIWebview is deprecated so your should your WKWebview.

For Flutter you should use below dependency :

```
webview_flutter: 0.3.15+1
```

Import this class :

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

Add this widget :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
      title: Text(this.title,centerTitle: true
  ),
  body: WebView(
  initialUrl: url,
  onPageFinished:(value){
    setState(() {
      print("====your page is load");
    });
  },
  )
);
}
```