# WebView can't display image tag url with http format in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, https, webview

when I try to display the image url from the api for the HTTP image tag format the image does not appear, while for https the image format appears.

the following code i use

```js
WebView(
              initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
                      "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'/>"
                      "${HtmlCodeHtpp}",
                      mimeType: 'text/html',
                      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
                  .toString(),
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
            ),
```

the data is obtained from existing submissions, for testing I use hard code first

```html
var HtmlCode = '<h1> h1 Heading Tag</h1>' +
      '<h2> h2 Heading Tag </h2>' +
      '<p> Sample Paragraph Tag </p>' +
      '<p><img src="https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/install_thumb.png" alt="Image" width="250" height="150" border="3"></p>' ;



  var HtmlCodeHtpp = '<h1> h1 Heading Tag</h1>' +
      '<h2> h2 Heading Tag </h2>' +
      '<p> Sample Paragraph Tag </p>' +
      '<p><img src="http://ditpsmp.kemdikbud.go.id/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Irganisasi-Siswa-Intra-Sekolah-03-scaled.jpg" alt="Image" width="250" height="150" border="3"></p>' ;
```

this when using http format

[image: User Image Format HTTP Url]

Comment: I think you need to disable Apple Transport Security. More detail please check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686699/flutter-webview-http-url-not-working-in-ios

Comment: any solution do you get?